# Ruby send to method hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have next code (they don't work):

```
def search_form(opts={})
  # Default options to form_tag
  default = { method: "post", controller: "search" }
  default.merge!(opts)

  render :layout => "welcome/search" do
    form_tag(default.extract!) do
      "Privet"
    end
  end
end
```

So i have default options in my helper, this code receive options as an argument.
How i can (unpack) my hash and don't write the ugly code:

```
form_tag(controller: default[:controller], action: default[:action]) do
  # Some code
end
```

I want something like that **(this just draft, prototype, unpack function is just example)**:

```
form_tag(default.unpack) do
  # Some code
end
```

**Note:** When i say unpack i mean something like from javascript

```
var fn = function(a, b, c){
  // Some code
}
fn.apply(null, [a, b, c]);
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: You can just pass the hash as it is, no need for any unpacking.

Comment: @Iceman don't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following should work:

```
def search_form(opts = { })
  options = { method: :post, controller: :search, action: :search }.merge(opts)

  render layout: 'welcome/search' do
    form_tag(options) do
      "Privet"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 4):

Just get rid of the `.extract!` call on the hash:

```
def search_form(opts={})
  # Default options to form_tag
  default = { method: "post", controller: "search" }
  default.merge!(opts)

  render :layout => "welcome/search" do
    form_tag(default) do
      "Privet"
    end
  end
end
```

From the docs for [`Hash#extract!`](http://apidock.com/rails/Hash/extract!):

> Removes and returns the key/value pairs matching the given keys.
>
> ```
> { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3, d: 4 }.extract!(:a, :b) # => {:a=>1, :b=>2}
> { a: 1, b: 2 }.extract!(:a, :x)             # => {:a=>1}
> ```

This means that `any_hash.extract!` (with no arguments) will return `{}`, which probably isn't what you want.